# Possible to enable additional fonts in Command Prompt without registry edits?

Tags: windows, command-line, fonts

I have a (Windows-compatible) open-type font I would like to use in Command Prompt, Powershell,  WSL, etc. I have installed it sucessfully and it shows up in other tools like Wordpad. However, it does not show up as an option within Command Prompt after right-clicking on the bar and choosing "Properties", then going to the "Font" tab. It's just not listed. Only a small number are.

I read online that this may require a registry edit. Is it possible to do so *without* a registry edit?

In case it is needed, the specific font is: "Fura Mono Medium Nerd Font Complete Mono Windows Compatible.otf"

I got it from here: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/FiraMono

Answer (score 1):

Likely the issue is that the font you've added is not correctly flagged as monospaced, or that it is installed *for one user* and unavailable to *another* (e.g., user *System*).

If the issue is the user, remove the font and reinstall, as Administrator, and make available to *all* users.

The CMD prompt should display any **valid monospaced font** that is **installed for all users.** [In addition to TrueType fonts, *fixed System* fonts also can be used.] *No Registry hack is used.*

Note the three conditions:

- Valid, i.e., there is no error in the font misidentifying it.
- Monospaced, not proportional.
- Installed for all users, including System.

An example of an added font, Google *Inconsolata*, being used is below.

[image: Using added font]

As for monospaced vs. proportional fonts:

The CMD prompt uses only [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), such as Courier New [installed  by default in Windows], and others such as [3270](https://github.com/rbanffy/3270font), Consolas, Deja Vu Sans Mono, [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata), Liberation Mono and Lucida Console. See [Wikipedia for yet more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) monospaced typefaces. Had you added a *monospaced* font, it *would* have appeared in the list of choices in *Preferences*.

There is a reason [proportional typefaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion) are *not* used. [Kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) of letters adjusts spacing to improve appearance and to use less space between letters. For example, the letters `AV` can be squeezed closely so as to overlap. This, however, destroys the width of columns, unless there is a tabulator (tab) between columns -- and traditional CMD prompt and terminals ignore tabs, which might inadvertently cause hard-to-diagnose issues in commands.

[image]

Notice in the image above that two "columns" were selected (date and time) by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting a range with a mouse. Proportional spacing would prevent letters from neatly lining up, one over the other.

Again, no Registry hack is needed, and I'd be suspicious of any such "requirement".

Comment: As the name "Fura Mono Medium" suggests, this is a monospace font, not a proportional font.

Comment: 1. The font should be available to the user. 2. The particular font may have issues, e.g., internally, not behaving as a monospaced font. Try installing another from a repuabtle source, such as Google's Inconsolata, to prove the point.

Comment: BTW, I'd be suspicious of a font requiring a Registry change to install or to use. Fonts *can* contain malware, though that does *not *mean the particular font mentioned above does. See https://www.extremetech.com/internet/308167-windows-zero-day-attack-lets-hackers-hide-malicious-code-in-fonts and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/how-do-i-know-if-a-font-is-malicious

Comment: The font did not specifically request it or mention it. When I searched around for help with generic font issues on Windows, the registry edit suggestions came up.

The Nerd Font family is generally well-known and respected group of fonts. I use this same font elsewhere just fine, it just seems the windows-compatible version may have some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly certain you cannot add new fonts to the Command Prompt without registry edits.  I assume the decision was not to allow someone to change the fonts to something someone could not read, like WingDings or a foreign language font, thereby making it virtually unusable.

Comment: Of course you can: as soon as I installed Inconsolata, for example, it was listed as an option in CMD. Use **monospaced** fonts. Before you're "fairly certain", test it!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik and how did it do it?  registry edit?

Comment: No, just add the font, as you would any other, and it's immediately available.

Comment: They changed this sometime during Windows 10. Before that, conhost would only offer specific fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Windows CMD tool, Powershell and WSL all only support True Type Fonts (.ttf) and not Open Type Fonts (.otf). See the explanation here: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/1110#issuecomment-1423726176

It also appears that some of the patched Nerd Fonts have .ttf versions, while others do not.

I found they had a version of Inconsolata as a patched Nerd Font (so it has the additional symbols needed for tools like LSDeluxe) and it has a .ttf version.

Unfortunately, it does *not* have the symbols needed for the Starship prompt to work properly. Every one I've tried so far has failed.